# MKNetwroking issue while "POST" request in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, mknetworkkit

I am developing an iOS application.
I am getting an issue while sending "POST" request to Java server using [**MKNetwrokingKit**](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) library in iOS.

Server side response I am getting is -

```
2013-02-06 15:15:19,527 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
2013-02-06 15:15:19,527 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/XtrWS].[Authentication]] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) Servlet.service() for servlet Authentication threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class xtremum.health.us.api.generic.StaticVariable$ClientType.Praxify_151/1.0 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/12.2.0
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:196)
    at xtremum.health.us.api.generic.StaticVariable$ClientType.valueOf(StaticVariable.java:1)
    at xtremum.health.us.webservice.Authentication.doPost(Authentication.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-02-06 15:15:39,061 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
2013-02-06 15:15:39,062 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) method name : login
2013-02-06 15:15:39,062 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) I am in default case 
2013-02-06 15:15:39,062 INFO  [xtremum.health.us.api.generic.StaticVariable] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) msg to client : 1405
2013-02-06 15:15:39,062 DEBUG [xtremum.health.us.api.generic.StaticVariable] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) msg : {"msgToClient":1405}
2013-02-06 15:16:41,437 WARN  [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-3) Parameters: Invalid chunk ignored.
```

Client side response is `NSUrlErrorDomain 500`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means it's an internal error of the Server.

This generally means the server got an exception and could treat your request correctly. This can happen when the server isn't correctly coded.

But this doesn't necessary means your request is 'correct' :
Let's imagine a POST request where you are suppose to send your login and password.
Imagine your request only send a login and the server isn't coded correctly and doesn't check the 2 variables exist before using it, it will result in a NullPointerException (in java).

Anyway you should getting in touch with the people in charge of the serveur so they can debug your request, see what got wrong and correct it to avoid a error 500 (which shoulnd't happen)

Meantime, looking at

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class xtremum.health.us.api.generic.StaticVariable$ClientType.Praxify_151/1.0 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/12.2.0

It looks like an authentification error, maybe they didn't create a ClientType for your request (or you forgot to fill this client type correctly ??)

Do you pass some authentification info to the server ?